# What is this trigonometric expression equal to?

Tags: trigonometry

If $\frac{cos{x}}{cos{y}}=\frac{a}{b}$, then $(a\times tan{x}+b\times tan{y})$ equals
(A)$(a+b)cot{\frac{x+y}{2}}$
(B)$(a+b)tan\frac{x+y}{2}$
(C)$(a+b)(tan\frac{x}{2}+tan\frac{y}{2})$
(D)$(a+b)(cot\frac{x}{2}+cot\frac{y}{2})$
I believe know the trigonometric formulas but I am just not able to reduce the given expression to any of the options. Help.

Comment: a good way when given options to choose from is so test the function at where it is undefined. Here $x,y=\pi/2,\pi/2$. That immediately removes the third and fourth options. By checking $x=y=0$, you can remove the first option as well. Now that you know it must be the second, work towards reducing it to that form.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/510108/if-frac-cos-x-cos-y-fracab-then-a-tan-x-b-tan-y-equals

Comment: @labbhattacharjee I wasn't aware that this question has already been asked. What can I do now?

Comment: @user140087, I don't think you've something to do :).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $x=y$ then the expression is $(a+b)\tan x$, so the only alternative that could possibly be true is (B): that is,
$$\hbox{if}\quad\frac{\cos x}{\cos y}=\frac{a}{b}\quad\hbox{then}\quad
  a\tan x+b\tan y=(a+b)\tan\frac{x+y}{2}\ .$$
It remains to prove it.

We have
$$\frac{a}{a+b}=\frac{\cos x}{\cos x+\cos y}\ ,\quad \frac{b}{a+b}=\frac{\cos y}{\cos x+\cos y}\ ,$$
so
$${\rm LHS}
  =(a+b)\frac{\sin x+\sin y}{\cos x+\cos y}
  =(a+b)\frac{\sin\frac{x+y}{2}\cos\frac{x-y}{2}}{\cos\frac{x+y}{2}\cos\frac{x-y}{2}}
  ={\rm RHS}\ .$$